# Как использовать настройки стиля 'marmaid' в 'nicegui'

Tags: python-3.x

Я создаю блок-схему с синтаксисом 'mermaid' в 'nicegui'. Я хочу использовать настройки стиля '%%{ init : { "theme" : "default", "flowchart" : { "curve" : "linear" }}}%%' , но вместо стилизованного изображения я получаю просто текст на экране

```
from nicegui import ui

ui.mermaid('''
%%{ init : { "theme" : "default", "flowchart" : { "curve" : "linear" }}}%%


flowchart LR
    f1 --> f2
    f2 --> f3
    f2 --> f4
''')

ui.run()
```

Основная задача - сделать стрелки с прямыми углами, а не изогнутыми